# HTML - Zooming in, need assistance

Tags: html, zooming

I'm new to coding, making my first ever website for a college assignment and it appears that when i zoom in on my website everything kind of clashes together any help would be really appreciated!

[The image at 67% zoom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvvdq.jpg)

[The image at 100% zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFKRd.jpg)

Code i am using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="w3.css">
      <style>
       div.relative {
     position: relative;
     left: 5px;
     top:  115px;
      border: 0px solid #73AD21;
     }
      </style>
<style>
a {
    color: Black;
}
</style>
 <title>The Steakhouse</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background-image: url("Backgroundlol.jpg");
 background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
<div>
h1 {
    position: center;
    left: 640px;
    top: 15px;
}
</div> 
</style>
<div>
<center>
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:800px; width:500px; height:25px"> <center> <font size="7" face="Agency FB"> <b> The Steakhouse! </b> </font> <br> <b> Why don't you up the steaks a little?! </b> </center></DIV>
 <a href="Homepage.html"><IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:5px; LEFT:2px; WIDTH:280px; HEIGHT:290px" SRC="steakhouse logo.png"></a>
 <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:5px; LEFT:400px; WIDTH:250px; HEIGHT:240px" SRC="a_burned.png">
 <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:5px; LEFT:1450px; WIDTH:250px; HEIGHT:250px" SRC="NRA1.png">
      
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/TheSteakHouse"> <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:675px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:75px; HEIGHT:75px" SRC="facebook.png"> </a>
 <a href="http://www.instagram.com/TheSteakHouse"> <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:775px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:75px; HEIGHT:75px" SRC="instagram.png">
 <a href="http://www.twitter.com/TheSteakHouse"> <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:875px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:75px; HEIGHT:75px" SRC="twitter.png">
 
  <ul>
  </div>
 <DIV style="position: absolute; top:300px; left:-380px; width:1000px; height:25px"> <center> <ul>
<font face="Agency FB" size="25" <li>LINKS:</li> </font> <br>
    <font face="Agency FB" size="25" <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li> </font> <br>
  <font face="Agency FB" size="25" <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li> </font> <br>
  <font face="Agency FB" size="25" <li><a href="Reservation.html">Reservation</a></li> </font> <br>
  <font face="Agency FB" size="25" <li><a href="Awards.html">Awards</a></li> </font> <br>
</ul> </center> </DIV>
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:765px; left:1000px; width:500px; height:25px"><h1> Recent News:</h1></DIV>
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:825px; left:890px; width:500px; height:25px"><H3>WEBSITE NOW OFFICIALLY LAUNCHED!</H3></DIV>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<center>` is ancient, use some modern technology. Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: The reason is that you are using pixel values. Try changing some of those to percentages. There is no reason to use `position:absolute;` on everything.

Comment: Not bad for a first website, but I think that you will need to redo it if you want to fix that problem. Here are some links for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, elements used in creating the website believe in being there pixel fixed weather situation changes or not. 
If you want to make a more dynamic website that works on various resolutions(assuming all are in the range of computer standard i.e. not small like mobile)
Break down the page into its core elements, for example Header, Body, Footer
create elements inside this based on percentages of the screen available 
for ex, if sidebar occupies 20% of the body then no matter what the situation in behaves relative. 
tips: create a main element and fix its height(lets say 300px header)
then you can define percentages in both height and width to various header elements.
Hope I could help, good luck.